# API REST - Modelos serializados no toman el hostname del server de produccion - Django REST Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy exponiendo una aplicación (por el momento es solo su esquema de usuarios) con *Django Rest Framework*, y me sucede que cada modelo que he serializado, en el atributo url, tengo es la dirección del localhost de mi máquina de desarrollo y no me toma el hostname de mi máquina de producción la cual está en *Amazon EC2*.

En esta imagen puede detallarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en el url de cada modelo que he serializado me tome el hostname de la máquina en donde estoy, en este caso mi servidor de producción que es una instancia *Amazon EC2*?

Estos son mis modelos serializados en `userprofiles/serializers.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import User, PlayerProfile, CoachProfile, ViewerProfile

from rest_framework import serializers

# Serializers define the API representation
# Exponse the model and their fields
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'url', 'id', 'username', 
            'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
            'email', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 
            'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'date_joined', 
            'is_player', 'is_coach', 'is_viewer', 'photo'
        )

class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')

class PlayerProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerProfile
        fields = ('url', 'user', 'full_name', 'position')

class CoachProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoachProfile
        fields = ('url', 'user', 'full_name')

class ViewerProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ViewerProfile
        fields = ('url', 'user', 'full_name', 'specialty')
```

Este es mi archivo `urls.py` global (no de la aplicación `userprofiles` que contiene los modelos serializados):

```py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home, home_files

from rest_framework import routers
from userprofiles import views

# Router provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'players', views.PlayerProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'coachs', views.CoachProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'views', views.ViewerProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),

    url(r'^(?P<filename>(robots.txt)|(humans.txt))$', home_files, name='home-files'),

    # Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),

    # If you're intending to use the browsable API you'll probably also want to add REST framework's
    # login and logout views.
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Y este es mi archivo `userprofiles/views.py`  en donde se exponen los modelos serializados:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import User, PlayerProfile, CoachProfile, ViewerProfile

from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer, PlayerProfileSerializer, CoachProfileSerializer, ViewerProfileSerializer

# Create your views here.

# Viewsets define the behavior of the view
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

class PlayerProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows players to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = PlayerProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayerProfileSerializer

class CoachProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows coachs to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = CoachProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoachProfileSerializer

class ViewerProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows viewers to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = ViewerProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ViewerProfileSerializer
```

Comment: Encontré esta pregunta, que puede orientarme un poco con este asunto. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669376/django-rest-framework-absolute-urls-with-nginx-always-return-127-0-0-1

Comment: lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: @fredyfx lo intenté con la recomendación del enlace que tengo en el primer comentario de la pregunta, pero no me resultó. Entonces decidí utilizar herramientas del tipo PaaS como heroku, y me resultó. Si deseas mirar, acá comparto el proceso de utilizar Django y Heroku http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6541/deploy-static-assets-to-heroku-from-local-machine-cant-open-file-manage-py Pero es raro, debo mirar bien como es el tema con esquemas del tipo IaaS como amazon o incluso localmente, dado que no me funcionó de esa manera. Saludos :)

Comment: excelente! Gracias por compartir. Por cierto si gustas experimentar en la nube de Microsoft: Azure, entra al programa de "Visual Studio Dev Essentials" y obtienes una serie para ello. Saludos

Comment: Si, hace tiempesito vi que Azure ya permite estos deployments también. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/ Que nota men. :D

Comment: me gusta mucho la nueva Microsoft! Gracias por compartir la nota

Comment: Microsoft desde mas o menos 2010 en adelante ha venido interiorizando y apropiando la filosofía de colaboración del OpenSource y es genial.

Comment: asi es mi estimado!