# Deploy static assets to heroku from local machine - can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

Estoy intentando desplegar mis archivos estáticos de mi aplicación que irá a heroku, en amazon s3, pues asi lo  tengo configurado en mis settings.

Cuando ejecuto el comando `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` tengo el siguiente error:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
Running python manage.py collectstatic on neurorehabilitation.... up, run.5168
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Esto es extraño para mi, debido a que actualmente me encuentro en el directorio en donde esta localizado el archivo `manage.py`

Intenté aplicar permisos al archivo `manage.py` mediante `chmod +x manage.py` pero el resultado es igual

Cuando ejecuto el comando `git push heroky master` sin desplegar los estáticos antes con `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic`, tengo este log:

```
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
remote:            for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
remote:            for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
remote:            for entry in os.listdir(path):
remote:        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/static'
```

Con un proyecto distinto si pude ejecutar exitosamente el comando  `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic``

No puedo entender la razón por la cual mi heroku toolbet no puede encontrar mi archivo `manage.py`

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Con el objetivo de tener un despliegue temprano de mi aplicación, he optado por desactivar la opción de archivos estáticos en la plataforma configurando la variable de entorno `DISABLE_COLLECT_STATIC` de esta forma:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
Setting config vars and restarting neurorehabilitation... done
DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 1
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master)
```

Así la cosas, cuando he hecho `git push heroku master` finalmente pude desplegar mi aplicación pues la notificación final fue:

```
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 46M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v15
remote:        https://neurorehabilitation.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/neurorehabilitation.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Como puede verse, en mi enlace principal https://neurorehabilitation.herokuapp.com/ existe un error, asumo que es debido a que no se colocaron o no se están relacionando los archivos estáticos ... no se si estoy en lo correcto ¿lo estoy?

Pero algo que me intriga es que puedo detallar el admin de Django https://neurorehabilitation.herokuapp.com/admin/ y es algo que me intriga debido a que el administrador Django también posee archivos estáticos, entonces no se si heroku esta o no trabajando con ellos ...

¿Qué habrá sucedido aquí en esta situación con mis archivos estáticos?

Sin embargo, seguí y esta vez si puedo desplegar remotamente sobre heroku acciones que involucren el comando `pyhon manage.py <acción>`, prueba de ello es que realice efectiva mis primera migraciones de mi aplicación:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python  manage.py migrate        
Running python manage.py migrate on neurorehabilitation.... up, run.7836
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, auth, userprofiles, sessions, medical_encounter_information, admin
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0002_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0003_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0001_initial... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0002_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0003_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0004_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0005_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0006_auto_20160225_2303... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0007_auto_20160229_2204... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0008_auto_20160229_2208... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0009_auto_20160301_0130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0010_auto_20160301_0312... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0011_auto_20160301_1525... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0012_auto_20160301_1601... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0013_auto_20160301_1606... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0014_auto_20160301_1629... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0015_auto_20160301_1633... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0016_auto_20160301_1636... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0004_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0005_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0006_auto_20160225_2303... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0007_auto_20160229_2204... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0008_auto_20160229_2208... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0009_auto_20160301_0130... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0010_auto_20160301_0312... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0011_auto_20160301_1525... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0012_auto_20160301_1601... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0013_auto_20160301_1606... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0014_auto_20160301_1629... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0015_auto_20160301_1633... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0016_auto_20160301_1636... OK
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master)
```

También logré crear en mi aplicación desplegada en heroku un super usuario para ella, desde mi toolbet local:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python  manage.py createsuperuser
Running python manage.py createsuperuser on neurorehabilitation.... up, run.5381

Username: bgarcial
Email address: bgarcial@sample.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Acto seguido desactivo la variable de entorno configurada anteriormente `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` (Lo que he hecho es borrarla desde mis heroku dashboard en los settings de mi aplicación)

Pero cuando quiero volver a ejecutar el comando `heroku run python  manage.py collectstatic` me pasa esto:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python  manage.py collectstatic
Running python manage.py collectstatic on neurorehabilitation.... up, run.9342

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/static'
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Viendo todo esto, asumo que el error está acá al final:

```
 directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
        for entry in os.listdir(path):
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/static'
```

Y asumo que en la aplicación remota que he desplegado no se encuentra el directorio `static` que al igual que en la local es desde alli de donde se originan para ser almacenados en un CDN, en este caso a amazon S3.

No se como enfrentar esto, ¿Por qué en mi deployment no se generan completos los directorios que tengo en mi local machine?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

He ejecutado `heroku run bash` para detallar la estructura de directorios en mi aplicación en la nube y puedo detallar la raíz de mi proyecto, llamada  `/app` en heroku.

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run bash    
    Running bash on neurorehabilitation.... up, run.5840
    ~ $ pwd 
    /app
    ~ $
```

Al listar su contenido veo todos mis directorios y archivos, de manera similar a como los tengo en mi IDE/entorno de desarrollo

```
~ $ ls
avatars  custom_storages.py  django-multiselectfield-0.1.3.tar.gz  functional_tests  manage.py  medical_encounter_information  neurorehabilitation  Procfile  requirements  requirements.txt  runtime.txt  userprofiles
```

Como mi error tiene que ver con este archivo ...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/static'
```

Entonces entro a dicho directorio `/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/` pero veo que no existe un directorio llamado `static` ahí dentro como lo intenta buscar heroku

```
~ $ cd /app/neurorehabilitation/settings/
~/neurorehabilitation/settings $ ls
base.py  development.py  __init__.py  production.py  staging.py  testing.py
~/neurorehabilitation/settings $
```

Y esto es porque acorde a la estructura de directorios que yo he establecido cuando cree mi proyecto Django en mi entorno local de desarrollo, definí lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, acorde a esto, porque git al hacer deploy a heroku esta buscando una ruta `neurorehabilitation/settings/static` cuando esta no esta dada, desde la fuente original (mi máquina o entorno de desarrollo) ...

¿Qué podría hacer al respecto, pues heroku, cuando yo le doy `heroky run python manage.py collectstatic` éste busca un directorio que no existe o no esta contemplado en la estructura de archivos de mi proyecto?

Incluso creo que esa es la razón por la cual mis archivos estáticos no son mostrados, pues claro es obvio, no los subí en el `push`  entonces en mi url principal de la aplicación ya desplegada https://neurorehabilitation.herokuapp.com no se renderizan ni mis templates ni mis CSS ni mis JS porque supongo que acorde a lo que me sucede, heroku los  busca es en dicho directorio que no existe ¿verdad?

Aunque no se porque el admin si funciona https://neurorehabilitation.herokuapp.com/admin/ a pesar de ser una app (django-suit) pero esta tiene CSS JS y demás ...

**Es posible que no haya comprendido bien como trabaja heroku en el sentido de deployment en relación a los archivos y directorios**

Agradezco algún tipo de orientación :)

Comment: Para debuggear en Heroku, es muy cómodo usar `heroku run bash` así podés ver que archivos hay y cuales no, correr comandos varias veces, etc.

Comment: @eloyesp ¿podrías detallar mi **ACTUALIZACIÓN 2** por favor? no se si ese sea el problema, solo que en caso afirmativo, no se como abordarlo a nivel del deployment en heroku. Mucha gracias :)

Comment: Para que un directorio exista al clonar en git, necesitas crear un archivo dentro de ese directorio y agregarlo en git. `touch settings/static/.keep && git add settings/static/.keep && git commit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He querido crear una respuesta paso a paso tomando como referencias algunas orientaciones que he recibido (incluyendo las respuestas y comentarios de esta pregunta) y lo que he podido encontrar de recursos e información alrededor del tema.

A continuación compartiré el paso a paso que he realizado para el despliegue de mi aplicación en Heroku. Espero que lo que pueda escribir aquí pueda ser de utilidad.

1. **Configurando como trabajarán los archivos estáticos en los `settings` para desplegar a Heroku**

El inconveniente por el cual no podía desplegar mis archivos estáticos a Heroku estaba en la configuración de mi archivo `settings/base.py`

Específicamente, el inconveniente estaba en el valor que tenía mi directiva llamada `PROJECT_ROOT`.
[Heroku sugiere](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) que la directiva de configuración `PROJECT_ROOT` esté de esta forma:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Yo configuraba a `PROJECT_ROOT` (**la he llamado `BASE_DIR` en mi archivo `settings/base.py`** y asi se referenciará de acá en adelante en mi respuesta) tal como Heroku lo decía, pero el error siempre aparecía.

Lo que decidí fue que como BASE_DIR tiene un valor de configuración por defecto cuando se crea el proyecto Django, entonces lo dejé tal cual con ese valor y no como lo dice Heroku.

Asi las cosas, mi error que tenía, que era este:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/neurorehabilitation/settings/static'
```

era porque tenía a `BASE_DIR` de esta forma:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Entonces, para corregirlo, finalmente mi archivo `settings/base.py` para configurar mi aplicación y que sea desplegada en Heroku, ha quedado de esta forma:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

# This line tells Django to look for static files in a folder named static inside each of our apps.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

En realidad la raíz del error está en el valor que tomaba la directiva `STATICFILES_DIRS` que es la que finalmente marca la pauta en relación a la estructura de directorios de los archivos estáticos sin importar la infraestructura en donde estén desplegados.

Al tener configurado mi BASE_DIR de una forma, esto incide en el valor que toma `STATICFILES_DIRS`, la cual queda de esta forma también para un correcto despĺiegue de mi aplicación: (creo que es asi como la pone por defecto Django, asu que no hay que mover nada con ella)

```
# With this configuration, Django will look for static files in a folder named static inside each app and into the neurorehabilitation/static folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Como yo tengo un [directorio de settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAJU.png) (`settings/{base.py, development.py,production.py,testing.py,staging.py}`) y como en estos momentos me dispongo a poner en producción mi aplicación en Heroku, entonces debo configurar de manera apropiada mi archivo `settings/production.py` pues es el que tomara Heroku para la configuración del despliegue.

Mi archivo `settings/production.py` en relación a Heroku queda de esta forma:

```
# Heredo del archivo settings/base.py que es en donde estan las
# configuraciones base o comunes de mi proyecto Django 
from .base import *
import dj_database_url

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

# ------ *** -------------
# For deploy to heroku
# ------ *** -------------

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Vale la pena resaltar que si no se tiene un conjunto de settings como lo tengo acá, todas estas configuraciones pueden ir en el archivo settings.py que por defecto genera Django cuando se crea el proyecto.

> Por si consideran necesario saber como configurar un conjunto de
>   settings.py, la genial [Marina Mele](https://twitter.com/Marina_Mele) lo explica de esta forma en su
>   [blog](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/settings-different-environments-version-control#different-settings) el cual recomiendo visitar y leer, es muy útil.

Adicionalmente, también es necesario instalar el paquete `dj-database-url` en mi entorno virtual que uso en mi máquina

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ pip install dj-database-url
Collecting dj-database-url
Installing collected packages: dj-database-url
Successfully installed dj-database-url-0.4.0
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

y asi mismo adicionarlo a mi archivo de `requirements/production.txt` de esta forma

```
dj-database-url==0.4.0
```

Para los requerimientos de paquetes, también se tiene un conjunto de archivos de esta forma `requirements/{base.txt,development.txt,production.txt,testing.txt}` acorde [a esta definición u orientación](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/settings-different-environments-version-control#environments-requirements)

> En este punto del **numeral 1** básicamente describo la razón por la
>   cual el comando `collectstatic` no me funcionaba cuando desplegaba mi
>   aplicación en heroku y se intentaba copiar y procesar mis archivos
>   estáticos a Amazon S3 que es en donde los tengo.

Entonces, además, también he querido compartir el proceso de despliegue de mi aplicación Django en Heroku y otros requisitos para que se haga efectivo.

2. **Otros archivos necesarios**

Adicionalmente, para que el proceso de despligue sea exitoso, es necesario tener en la raíz de mi proyecto los siguientes archivos:

---

**requirements.txt**: Como había mencionado anteriormente, tengo este conjunto de archivos para las dependencias de mis paquetes `requirements/{base.txt,development.txt,production.txt,testing.txt}`

Entonces [en la raíz de mi proyecto creo un archivo llamado `requirements.txt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAJU.png) (ver recuadro amarillo en el enlace) con el siguiente contenido:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ cat requirements.txt 
-r requirements/production.txt%                                                 (nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Y mi archivo `requirements/production.txt` ha quedado asi:

```
-r base.txt
gunicorn==19.4.5
dj-database-url==0.4.0
```

El archivo `requirements/base.txt` contiene todas las dependencias o paquetes necesarios que son base para mi aplicación.

---

**runtime.txt**

Acorde [a este enlace](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), es necesario que Heroku instale la versión de python con la cual estamos trabajando, en mi caso, tengo la 3.4.3, por lo que el contenido de mi archivo runtime.txt (que también debe ir en la raíz de mi proyecto) es:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ cat runtime.txt 
python-3.4.3
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

**Procfile**

Segun [este enlace](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#the-procfile) el archivo `Procfile`

> define los tipos de proceso y declara explícitamente que comando debe
>   ser ejecutado para inicializar mi aplicación.

Con relación a esta definición, básicamente lo que hacemos es que nuestro archivo `Procfile` tendrá la instrucción que habilitará el servidor gunicorn que tomará las peticiones y las redirigirá a python, por lo cual es WSGI

Asi las cosas, el archivo Procfile en la raíz del proyecto debe quedar asi:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ cat Procfile 
web: gunicorn neurorehabilitation.wsgi --log-file -
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

3. **Probando el acceso desde mi máquina a través de Heroku Toolbet**

Es necesario instalar [Heroku Toolbet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#set-up) el cual proporciona acceso a una interfaz de línea de comandos de Heroku (basicamente es una porción o un sistema operativo unix de la maquina en donde esta alojada mi aplicación en Heroku) la cual es utilizada para administrar y escalar aplicaciones asi como extensiones, entre otras cosas.

Probamos el acceso a Heroku desde nuestra máquina de esta forma:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: botibagl@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Logged in as botibagl@gmail.com
(nrb_dev) ➜
```

4. **Creando mi aplicación en Heroku**

Acorde [a esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089754/deploy-django-to-heroku-push-rejected?noredirect=1#comment60109331_36089754) como mi aplicación a desplegar es python y Django, la aplicación en Heroku desde la herramienta toolbet debe ser creada de esta manera:

```
 (nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku create test-nrb --buildpack heroku/python
Creating test-nrb... done, stack is cedar-14
Setting buildpack to heroku/python... done
https://test-nrb.herokuapp.com | https://git.heroku.com/test-nrb.git
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Entonces, de esta manera, mi aplicación Heroku se crea en mi dashboard en mi cuenta web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. **Configurando las variables de entorno que tengo definidas en mi proyecto para que Heroku las entienda**

Particularmente en mi proyecto, en mi entorno virtual en mi maquina local, tengo algunas variables de entorno definidas.
Algunas son utilizadas para ocultar valores como el de mis `SECRET_KEY`'s, `DATABASE_USER`, `DATABASE_NAME`, `DATABASE_PASSWORD`, y como estoy utilizando Amazon S3 para alojar mis archivos estáticos, entonces también utilizo algunas claves e identificadores para acceder a estos recursos en Amazon.

Entonces como decíamos, es necesario indicarle a Heroku la forma en la que él conocerá estas variables de entorno.

De acuerdo a este enlace, se configuran las siguientes variables via heroku toolbeet de esta forma:

- **`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`**

Mi despliegue, a nivel de configuración, será guiado por el archivo `settings/production.py` el cual hereda de `settings/base.py` que es el que tiene todas las dependencias necesarias desde la perspectiva del dominio de mi aplicación.

Entonces la variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` en Heroku sera configurada de esta forma:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=neurorehabilitation.settings.production 
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: neurorehabilitation.settings.production
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

- **`SECRET_KEY`**

Para `SECRET_KEY` la configuración es la siguiente:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='my_secret_key'
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
SECRET_KEY: 6o_g=0jeqp4)b4q!tt+ic4cgxs^0s=$_rtokd1ndja=4f(9&74
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

---

Para el acceso a la base de datos, se configuran las siguientes variables:

- **`DATABASE_NAME`**

Nombre de la base de datos:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set DATABASE_NAME=mydatabasename
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
DATABASE_NAME: mydatabasename
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

- **`DATABASE_USER`**

Usuario de la base de datos:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set DATABASE_USER=mydatabaseuser
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
DATABASE_USER: mydatabaseuser
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

- **`DATABASE_PASSWORD`**

Contraseña de la base de datos, el password debe ir en comillas simples

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set DATABASE_PASSWORD='mydatabasepassword'
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
DATABASE_PASSWORD: mydatabasepassword
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

---

Para acceder a Amazon S3 es necesario configurar las siguientes variables:

- **Amazon Web Services Access Key ID**

El valor del ID debe ir en comillas simples

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='my_aws_access_key_id'
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: my_aws_access_key_id
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

- **Amazon Web Services Secret Access Key**

El valor de la clave debe ir en comillas simples

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='my_aws_secret_access_key'
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: my_aws_secret_access_key
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

- **Amazon Web Services Storage Bucket name**

El valor del nombre del bucket (unidad de almacenamiento en Amazon) debe ir en comillas simples

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku config:set AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='my-bucket-name-in-s3' 
Setting config vars and restarting test-nrb... done
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: my-bucket-name-in-s3
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

Entonces, acorde a las opciones de arriba, en mi dashboard web, las variables de entorno han quedado asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Confirmando los cambios en mi proyecto (`git commit`) al repositorio de mi aplicación en Heroku

Primero examinamos los archivos que ha sido agregados y están en fase de `staging` o están listos para ser confirmados:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   requirements.txt
    new file:   runtime.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   neurorehabilitation/settings/base.py
    modified:   neurorehabilitation/settings/development.py
    modified:   neurorehabilitation/settings/production.py
    modified:   requirements.txt
    modified:   runtime.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/
    Procfile
    gunicorn_start

(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master)

(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add requirements.txt 
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add runtime.txt     
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add Procfile 
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ 

(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add neurorehabilitation/settings/base.py 
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add neurorehabilitation/settings/development.py
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git add neurorehabilitation/settings/production.py
```

Realizamos la operación de `commit`

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git commit -m 'Setup changes and configurations for deploy to heroku'
[master 69d69fe] Setup changes and configurations for deploy to heroku
 6 files changed, 38 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Procfile
 create mode 100644 requirements.txt
 create mode 100644 runtime.txt
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

7. **Desplegamos el código de nuestra aplicación al repositorio que heroku ha creado para ella**

Antes de ello, es bueno que nos cercioremos que repositorios remotos o alias tenemos asignados. Es importante, porque el alias de `heroku` es el que debemos tener en cuenta para el deployment al repositorio que heroku crea al crear la aplicación.

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/neurorehabilitation.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/neurorehabilitation.git (push)
origin  https://bgarcial@bitbucket.org/bgarcial/neurorehabilitation_projects.git (fetch)
origin  https://bgarcial@bitbucket.org/bgarcial/neurorehabilitation_projects.git (push)
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

**Desplegamos la aplicación al repositorio heroku**

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master 
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.17 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote: 
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/forms.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
remote:        147 static files copied.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 46.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v15
remote:        https://test-nrb.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/test-nrb.git
   9f0d32f..fcc62c9  master -> master
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

8. **Ejecutamos las migraciones de nuestra aplicación**

Realizamos el proceso de migración para que se hagan efectivos nuestros modelos:

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on test-nrb.... up, run.1678
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: medical_encounter_information, userprofiles, contenttypes, auth, admin, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0002_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0003_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0001_initial... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0002_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0003_auto_20160225_2130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0004_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0005_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0006_auto_20160225_2303... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0007_auto_20160229_2204... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0008_auto_20160229_2208... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0009_auto_20160301_0130... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0010_auto_20160301_0312... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0011_auto_20160301_1525... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0012_auto_20160301_1601... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0013_auto_20160301_1606... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0014_auto_20160301_1629... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0015_auto_20160301_1633... OK
  Applying medical_encounter_information.0016_auto_20160301_1636... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0004_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0005_auto_20160225_2211... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0006_auto_20160225_2303... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0007_auto_20160229_2204... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0008_auto_20160229_2208... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0009_auto_20160301_0130... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0010_auto_20160301_0312... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0011_auto_20160301_1525... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0012_auto_20160301_1601... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0013_auto_20160301_1606... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0014_auto_20160301_1629... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0015_auto_20160301_1633... OK
  Applying userprofiles.0016_auto_20160301_1636... OK
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

9. Creo mi super usuario en mi aplicación

A traves de `createsuperuser`

```
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗ heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
Running python manage.py createsuperuser on test-nrb.... up, run.7499
Username: bgarcial
Email address: bgarcial@eafit.edu.co
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
(nrb_dev) ➜  neurorehabilitation_projects git:(master) ✗
```

---

Y es así como queda mi aplicación desplegada en la plataforma heroku https://test-nrb.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

Git no guarda directorios, solo archivos y sólo crea los directorios al clonar que tienen archivos adentro, por lo tanto, puede que si el directorio está vacío (o sea que no hay ningún archivo que esté trackeado en git dentro del directorio) entonces heroku no va a tener dicho directorio.

Además tenes que tener en cuenta que en heroku no tenés permiso de escritura en `/app`, si necesitas escribir archivos (incluso de forma temporal al compilar) tenés que hacerlo en `/tmp`